# Getting dispatch types correct for redux-thunk

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-thunk

I would really like to be able to use full typing with typescript and not have to re-implement types with potentially conflicting signatures.

In this case I would like to use the call/return signature from loadUserList and still have it work for dispatch and connect.

loadUserList is a redux-thunk function, so and it will eventually return a string once it goes through the middleware. However the prototype that I need to send to `DispatchProps` is different than what I sent to `CDispatchProps` (the props to send to the connect function).

While I could just change `CDispatchProps` to `any` that really wouldn't solve my primary goal which is to import the type signature from `userList.tsx` so that both the arguments and returns have type safety (I'm willing to give it up to connect -- since it's in the "black box" category).

Maybe the best route is some typescript magic that will extract the argument type and the return type from the ThunkAction<...> in a reasonable way.

**UserListPage.tsx**

```
import { loadUserList, UserQuery } from "../store/actions/userList";

type DispatchProps = {
  loadUserList: (query: UserQuery) => string,
};

type CDispatchProps = {
  loadUserList: typeof loadUserList,
};

class UserListPage extends React.Component<Props & DispatchProps, State> {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.setState({ id: this.props.loadUserList(this.state.query) });
  }
}

export default connect<any, CDispatchProps, Props>((store: Store) => ({
  users: store.userList.entities,
  loading: store.userList.fetchStatus,
}), { loadUserList })(UserListPage);
```

**userList.ts**

```
export function loadPrivateUserList(options: UserQuery, force?: boolean): ThunkAction<string, State, null> {
  return (dispatch: redux.Dispatch<State>, getState: () => State): string => {
    const { userList } = getState();
    const id = computeID(options);

    // Do some async actions

    return id;
  }
}
```